# What is the best way to invoke a lambda from another one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I need your experience to determine which is the best tool to invoke an AWS lambda from another one. Here are the known tools, if you can give me your pros and cons for the one you know and its efficiency:

### Invoke function

### DynamoDB Stream

### Kinesis Stream

### SNS

### SQS

### S3 Bucket and Put Object

### Any other proposal?

Thanks a lot for your help to determine the best strategy.

Note: I am using serverless and NodeJS if it can lead to another compatible option.

In my case, I have no real problem. I just want to take advantage of your experiences using this tool. I both need s3 for PDF files and dynamoDB to store. I just would like to use one of the available tool to communicate between my different components (lambdas) of my API. Maybe some of you think SNS should be the best option. Why. Some other S3? etc. This is not specific if my usage but yours in fact ;-) I think it is just difficult to determine the best adapted choice  for a newcomer. In my case I would like to uniformize my communication between my   different services (modularity/reproductive method) without any constraint of what service actually does. A kind of universal lambda communication tool.

Comment: Please Edit your question and provide more information about your use-case. What are you currently doing? WHY do you want to invoke another Lambda function -- what are you currently unable to achieve? What problems are you experiencing? The better you can describe your situation, the better the answer you will receive.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein and now?

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about this in the wrong way. You don't choose one mechanism over another like this. Instead, the mechanism is dictated by how events are being generated. Did an update happen to a DynamoDB table? Then a DynamoDB Streams event triggers a Lambda function. Did a file get uploaded to S3? Then an S3 object uploaded event triggers a Lambda function.

Comment: I need it in both cases. I just want a method that could be quite ease-of-use and relevant that can be used in all cases.

Comment: Lambda A can invoke Lambda B directly (SDKs have sync and async invocation options) plus you can front Lambda with API Gateway allowing clients to make authenticated API calls that cause Lambda invocation. That said, the lack of a concrete requirements statement here makes it difficult to understand if Lambda is the right solution (I suspect it is not).